Do cooked oysters contain hemolymph?
With Thanksgiving season happening in the U.S., oyster stuffing is common to eat. However, some people, for various reasons, may find it objectionable to consume blood or blood-analogues such as hemolymph.
Do cooked oysters still contain more than a trace amount of hemolymph?

You'd be better off asking this in one of our sister religious sites; Christianity, if you are christian (assumed because of Genesis and Acts). AFAIK the new testament declares all foods clean. I'm sure someone has asked this somewhere on the internet before- try searching "can I eat shellfish {your religion}" should give you a decent start.

I’m voting to close this question because its a question for your religious leaders as to whether you can eat shellfish - no-one "bleeds" them, like you do with an animal.

@bob1: The question has been bifurcated; an answer to this half can be provided with no understanding of Christianity. The religious half is in fact on christianity.stackexchange.com. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/104069/57

@bob1 What Joshua said. Someone on Christianity Stack Exchange told me the question would be better asked here, lol: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/104069/if-blood-is-prohibited-what-about-hemolymph

This is indeed a long standing problem with migration suggestions - people who suggest a migration to another site usually don't know either the scope of the target site, or the rule that "if it fits on the original site, it stays there even if the target could also take it". In this case, I think the question is fine as written. We will have to take care that the answers also stay in the cooking context, that is, not judgements of whether the OP should eat oysters, but strictly whether they contain hemolymph.

That "someone" was me.  I feel confident that "do cooked oysters still contain more than a trace amount of hemolymph?" is on topic, as it is clearly asking about food preparation. I've proposed an edit to remove the religious context in order to not distract from the question being asked here.

@Matthew And I’ve just accepted your edit! With your suggestion implemented, this game of “Migration Chairs” should hopefully be over now.

Short answer: Yes, they contain hemolymph.
Mammals are bled during slaughter by cutting a major artery in the neck. Molluscs (osysters are part of the mollusc group, along with snails, octopus and many others) do have a couple of major arteries (labeled Anterior aorta and Posterior aorta on the image below), but these are tiny, so trying to bleed one would be both very fiddly and destroy much of the form of the animal, so would be a waste of time and effort as I'm not sure that their circulatory system is under much pressure at all.
Like most shellfish, oysters are cooked whole and from alive, so the hemolymph should be present in the animal when cooked.

Image attribution: KDS444, CC BY-SA 3.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0, via Wikimedia Commons

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. I understand that the purpose of the question was to decide whether oysters are biblically permissible, but that's a discussion we explicitly don't want to have on the site. All we can do is to provide the technical information about the presence/absence of hemolymph after cooking; the OP has to find out elsewhere what implications this has for his religious practice.
